# Spacing between custom verbatim environments

Tags: spacing, lists, fancyvrb

I have a document that uses multiple custom verbatim environments, created using the [fancyvrb package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb). Spacing around these is controlled by my own code; I have disabled the spacing added by `fancyvrb` using

```
\let\FV@ListVSpace\relax
```

However, when two verbatim environments appear inside an `itemize` (or
other list environment), a vertical space is inserted between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{mapleerror}{Verbatim}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
Implied multiplication is not supported in Maple notation. 
Omitting an asterisk will usually lead to an error message.
\medskip
\makeatletter
\let\FV@ListVSpace\relax
\makeatother
\begin{code}
2 sin( Pi ) ; 
\end{code}
\begin{mapleerror}
Error, missing operator or `;`
\end{mapleerror}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: spacing]

What causes the unwanted space, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to clear also the internal parameter `\@topsepadd`; better doing it in a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{mapleerror}{Verbatim}{}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tightcodes}
 {\let\FV@ListVSpace\relax\@topsepadd=0pt }
 {}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
Implied multiplication is not supported in Maple notation. 
Omitting an asterisk will usually lead to an error message.
\medskip
\begin{tightcodes}
\begin{code}
2 sin( Pi ) ; 
\end{code}
\begin{mapleerror}
Error, missing operator or `;`
\end{mapleerror}
\end{tightcodes}

\item Something else
\end{itemize}

\begin{tightcodes}
\begin{code}
2 sin( Pi ) ; 
\end{code}
\begin{mapleerror}
Error, missing operator or `;`
\end{mapleerror}
\end{tightcodes}

\end{document}
```

[image]